# How to open audio and video files in lightbox in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, audio, video, plugins

I want to open the audio and video files through the plugin in the wordpress.and i am currently use the plugin wp video lightbox plugin in the wordpress.

I have iframe code like..

```
<iframe width="325" height="64" src="http://www.ewihosting.com/evp/?id=Mi0wMSBJbnRlcm5ldCBSaWNoZXMgTWFkZSBFYXN5Lm1wMw%3D%3D&profile=default&mode=iframe" frameborder="0" style="background:#fff;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and i use the logic like..

```
<li>
<a href="http://www.ewihosting.com/evp/?id=MS0wMSBJbnRlcm5ldCBSaWNoZXMgTWFkZSBFYXN5Lm1wMw%3D%3D&profile=default&mode=iframe" rel="wp-video-lightbox[iframes]"><span class="audio_upload_icon"></span><h3>Audio</h3><h4>Lesson #1</h4></a>
</li>
```

and i click on the image then open the lightbox but my audio file is not working but may video file is working are correctly.

So please advise me to which plugin very useful for me or any done the code modification.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are self hosting your Wordpress, or at least you have access to your ftp files in your hosting service. If so, then:
You may wish to save a myvideo.html file in your server, then invoke it via

```
<li>
<a href="myvideo.html" rel="wp-video-lightbox[iframes]">
<span class="audio_upload_icon"></span>
<h3>Audio</h3>
<h4>Lesson #1</h4>
</a>
</li>
```

You can include the full path of your local html files, which allow you to make a folder inside of which you can save all your needed iframes, the code will look like this:

```
<li>
<a href="myvideo.html" rel="wp-video-lightbox[iframes]">
<span class="audio_upload_icon"></span>
<h3>Audio</h3>
<h4>Lesson #1</h4>
</a>
</li>
```

Lightbox, Shadowbox and other similar tools/plugins will now work. BUT if you are not self-hosting your wordpress nor be able to gain access to the files on your web hosting, you will need a different solution. Please let us know what is the case in order to provide the proper support.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fancbox](http://fancybox.net/) Jquery Plugin.

Its pretty simple and usage. For more [click here](http://fancybox.net/data/iframe.html).